# How to make webpage 100% width using bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap i have requirement where user is asking to make layout 100% height and width that should cover all the space on the page. I tried bootstrap class .container-fluid but its not working. Any idea what i am doing wrong in below code ?

index.html

```
 <div id="main-content" style="padding-bottom: 3rem;" ng-if="user">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <breadcrumbs></breadcrumbs>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a native class in Bootstrap that handles 100% height, and `.container-fluid` still has the 15px of padding on the right and left, so that's not truly 100%. You will likely need to use custom css to achieve this.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to duplicate the issue with the width. If I add borders to those divs, they use the entire width of the page.

Comment: As for the height, the answer you want is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: You should edit your question, so that It refers to height and not width. Bootstrap is always 100% width by default.

Answer (score -2):

**aftab** Have a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfr596nr/)**.
You can make a `class` and use `vh` and `vw` (height/width).

You will see the **block** `class` takes 50px away from the overall view port height for the height of the navbar.

```
.block {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* less 50px for the height of the Navbar */
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: darkorange;
}
```

Notice this fills the whole screen with no scroll bars. 
See if this helps you here.

Just have a read of **[this](http://caniuse.com/#search=Vh)** for browser support.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin, still completing this post. So please do not be so quick to judge. I have made a complete working fiddle for this post.

Comment: Consider completing posts before you hit the "Post your answer" button.